# How use pattern matching for SQL style queries against JSON or JSON lines

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

Starting with data in the form of [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) or [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org/), I want to use [structural pattern matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) to run queries against it.

For example, after running json.load() I get a dict structured like this:

```
publications = {
    'location': 'central library',
    'items': [
        {'kind': 'book', 'title': 'Python in Aviation'},
        {'kind': 'magazine', 'title': 'Flying Monthly', 'issues': 15},
        {'kind': 'book', 'title': 'Python for Rock Climbers'},
        {'kind': 'magazine', 'title': 'Weekly Climber', 'issues': 42},        
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is apply Python 3.10's structural pattern matching extract relevant data much l[ike](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) I would with this SQL query:

```
SELECT title, issues FROM Publications WHERE kind = "magazine";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mapping Patterns

The key to the solution is to apply [mapping patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#mapping-patterns).  Per PEP 634, they have the form:

```
mapping_pattern: '{' [items_pattern] '}'
items_pattern: ','.key_value_pattern+ ','?
key_value_pattern:
    | (literal_pattern | value_pattern) ':' pattern
    | double_star_pattern
double_star_pattern: '**' capture_pattern
```

In everyday language, this means "write a dictionary with curly braces putting in constants for values you want to match on and putting in variables for the fields you want to extract."

### Worked-out example

Using the data supplied in the question, here is how you would translate the requested SQL query:

```
for item in publications['items']:
    match item:
        case {'kind': 'magazine', 'title': title, 'issues': issues}:
            print(f'{title} has {issues} issues on hand')
```

This filters *items* to only include magazines. Then it extracts the *title* and *issues* fields.  This outputs:

```
Flying Monthly has 15 issues on hand
Weekly Climber has 42 issues on hand
```